# How to encrypt an ASCII character with textbook RSA in C#?

Tags: c#, math, encryption, rsa, modular-arithmetic

I have a problem with calculate of ASCII value with exponent and modulus.
I want calculate ASCII value of "K" with RSA algorithm.

K in ascii value is 75

```
c   = m^e mod n
    = 75^41 mod 689
    = 316
```

Then how to make it into source code in C#? I got error "cannot implicity convert  type".

this my source code

```
int n = 689;
int e = 41;
int d = 137;
string value = "K";

for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
{
    int c = (int)i;
    c = Math.Pow(i,e);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Not sure if it's related to your error message, but you seem to have an error in your code, the inner part of the for loop should work on `value[i]` instead of `i`.

Answer (score 3):

Since `75^41` will overflow if cast to an `int` you have to do a little math trick.  `A*B mod N` is equivalent to `(A mod N) * (B mod N) mod N`, so you just do the multiplication in a loop, taking the remainder each time:

```
public static int PowModN(int a, int b, int n)
{
    a = a % n;
    int c = 1;
    for(int i=1; i <= b; i++)
        c = (c*a % n);

    return c;
}
```

and change your loop to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
{
    int c = (int)i;
    c = PowModN(i,e,n);
}
```

Comment: i have use your method but the result still error,
the error message is like this
"Error 4 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'ConsoleApplication1.Program.PowModN(int, int, int)'"

Comment: If all of your code is in `static Main` then you can make `PowModN` `static` as well.  I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Great catch, James.  Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
string value = "K";

// Convert the string into a byte[].
byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value);
```

Once you get the array out put you can set it to a variable and do whatever math you need to do.

Comment: i have use that method but when i operate it with math.pow() , that make an error,

Comment: Math.pow output is a double, not an int. cast it to an int or make your variable a double. i also believe the interior parameters need to be doubles as well.

Answer (score 0):

The output of `Math.Pow` is a double, and takes two floats as arguments. At the very least, cast the output of `Math.Pow(i,e)` to be an int, like so:

```
c = (int)Math.Pow(i,e)
```

This is one of the worst things about C#, imo. Not sure why it doesn't innately support integer exponentiation.

What type is `i`? It might need to be casted to doubles as well.

Comment: `75^41` will overflow if cast to `int`.